# flutter authentication: multiple flutter apps in one firebase project

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have one Firebase project with two android apps

I use the same databases and everything but I want to use different authentication for each one of them.

Is there any rules for the authentication feature or what should I do to implement this?

Comment: I create standalone google account for each flutter app

Comment: @rstrelba You mean different firebase projects? I need them to access the same databases but different authentication services.